# XPath - find curly brackets with contains

Tags: php, xpath

I need to find nodes which contain strings like that: `{string}`
I would like to do it like that:

```
$nodeList = $xpath->query(".//*[text()[contains(.,'{" . $key . "}')]]", $dom);
```

I tried putting html, unicode etc codes there instead of curly brackets, also doubled the brackets, put slash (`\`) before them etc and it didn't work. How should it be accomplished?

Comment: The XPath `//*[text()[contains(., "{string}")]]` works correctly. Are you sure `$key` has the correct value?

Comment: oh damn, you are right, I must have had something other wrong, now it works. thanks for making me realize :P